# Having two views horizontally fill a container viewer?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to have two Views fill an entire container view, but for some reason I can't really do it in a satisfactory manner - The only way I've managed to do it was using absolute width which seems like a bad practice to me.

My goal is having a View that contains a several rows (gridLine), where each row contains two clickable views (gridButton).

This is the style for the parent View:

```
gridLine: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignContent: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    overflow: 'hidden',
}
```

This is the style for the children Views:

```
gridButton: {
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'darkgrey',
        backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        height: 50,
        width: '50%', // I tried putting it to null, '100%', nothing works :(
    }
```

And this is its actual usage:

```
<View style={styles.gridLine}>
    <TouchableHighlight>
        <View style={styles.gridButton}>
            <Text>Text1</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    <TouchableHighlight>
        <View style={styles.gridButton}>
            <Text>Text1</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

This is how it is now:
[image: Bad style :(]

This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

Live example of the issue:
https://snack.expo.io/SkfLNbiFZ

Comment: You can use FlatList with 2 columns and render the components as you want.

Comment: That's a good answer, I've actually managed to do it that way. You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FlatList with 2 columns and render the components as you want.
If you want variable height components you can use this library 
https://github.com/AppAndFlow/react-native-masonry-list which is based on FlatList itself.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const equalWidth = width/2;
export default class flatlistDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      buttonList: [
        {
          id:1,
          buttonText: "ARG1",
        },
        {
          id:2,
          buttonText: "ARG2",
        },
        {
          id:3,
          buttonText: "ARG3",
        },
        {
          id:4,
          buttonText: "ARG4",
        }, {
          id:5,
          buttonText: "ARG5",
        }
        , {
          id:6,
          buttonText: "ARG6",
        }
      ]
    }
  }


  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  renderRowItem = (itemData) => {
    return (

      <TouchableHighlight style={{ height: 50, margin:5,backgroundColor: '#000000', width: equalWidth -10}}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>{itemData.item.buttonText}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList

        data={this.state.buttonList}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderRowItem}
      />

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('flatlistDemo', () => flatlistDemo);
```

Comment: It appears like this has the same problem, I tried to have same thing just with flat list, but the components still won't fill the parent component

Comment: Wait let me try then I will revert you back

Comment: you can get dimentions and then set the width of each component inside flatlist to be width/2

Comment: This also works, but there is around 2 seconds delay before the actual onLayout event fires and the dimensions of the container view updates :(

Comment: I was little busy, just trying your problem at my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153637/discussion-between-paras-watts-and-nadavl).